# Swift: how to distinguish a global variable from a class member?

Tags: swift, naming

Say you have a class with a title member you have to assign with a global variable that sports the same name.

How to distinguish between the two?

```
var title = "Hello"

class ThisClass {

       var title = ""

       func aMethod () {

            self.title = title
       }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scope of the "global" variable `title` is the module defined by your Xcode project. By default, its name is that of your target. So, if your code is in a project that builds an app called `MyApp`, you can do this:

```
var title = "Hello"

class ThisClass {    
       var title = ""
       func aMethod () {
            self.title = MyApp.title
       }
}
```